# Remove "-scaled" from automatically scaled image Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

WordPress automatically scale images having dimensions more than 2000px.
I just want to remove the -scaled from the end of the filename and the image-url probably. I know the big_image_size_threshold saves the orignal copy of the image. I don't care about the image with original size. I just want the -scaled removed.

I tried to rename the file using the function but it didn't worked. I think the scaling process is running after

```
function wpa59168_rename_attachment( $post_ID ) {

    $post = get_post( $post_ID );
    $file = get_attached_file( $post_ID );
    $path = pathinfo( $file );

    $new_name=str_replace('-scaled', '', $path['filename']);
    $new_file = $path['dirname'] . '/' . $new_name . '.' . $path['extension'];
    rename( $file, $new_file );    
    update_attached_file( $post_ID, $new_file );

}
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'wpa59168_rename_attachment' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want the -scaled images either and i added this piece of code:

```
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', function ( $treshold, $imagesize, $file, $attachment_id ) {
        return false;
    }, 10, 4 );
```

This actually killed the -scaled image all together in my website. If that's what you're looking for. The original image with original dimension will still exist with no "-scaled" part in the filename

Comment: short version: `add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );`

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the '-scaled' filename part, you will obtain the original file name, but this will cause the rename( $file, $new_file ) call to fail because a file with the same name already exists.

Delete the original file before trying to rename the scaled version.

C.